# TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined AGAIN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, jsx

I'm getting this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined" , and it shows that it is something wrong in this line

```
controlPosition={google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT}
```

there is my code. Please help!!!

```
import React from "react";
const _ = require("lodash");
const { compose, withProps, lifecycle } = require("recompose");
const {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  google,
} = require("react-google-maps");
const { SearchBox } = require("react-google-maps/lib/components/places/SearchBox");

const SimpleMap = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
        loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `200%` }} />,
        containerElement: <div style={{ height: `500px` }} />,
        mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,

  }),
  lifecycle({
    componentWillMount() {
      const refs = {}

      this.setState({
        bounds: null,
        center: {
          lat: 34.4208, lng: -119.6982 
        },
        markers: [],
        onMapMounted: ref => {
          refs.map = ref;
        },
        onBoundsChanged: () => {
          this.setState({
            bounds: refs.map.getBounds(),
            center: refs.map.getCenter(),
          })
        },
        onSearchBoxMounted: ref => {
          refs.searchBox = ref;
        },
        onPlacesChanged: () => {
          const places = refs.searchBox.getPlaces();
          const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

          places.forEach(place => {
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport)
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location)
            }
          });
          const nextMarkers = places.map(place => ({
            position: place.geometry.location,
          }));
          const nextCenter = _.get(nextMarkers, '0.position', this.state.center);

          this.setState({
            center: nextCenter,
            markers: nextMarkers,
          });
          // refs.map.fitBounds(bounds);
        },
      })
    },
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props =>
  <GoogleMap
    ref={props.onMapMounted}
    defaultZoom={15}
    center={props.center}
    onBoundsChanged={props.onBoundsChanged}
  >
    <SearchBox
      ref={props.onSearchBoxMounted}
      bounds={props.bounds}
      controlPosition={google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT}
      onPlacesChanged={props.onPlacesChanged}
    >
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Customized your placeholder"
        style={{
          boxSizing: `border-box`,
          border: `1px solid transparent`,
          width: `240px`,
          height: `32px`,
          marginTop: `27px`,
          padding: `0 12px`,
          borderRadius: `3px`,
          boxShadow: `0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)`,
          fontSize: `14px`,
          outline: `none`,
          textOverflow: `ellipses`,
        }}
      />
    </SearchBox>
    {props.markers.map((marker, index) =>
      <Marker key={index} position={marker.position} />
    )}
  </GoogleMap>
);
export default SimpleMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `react-google-maps` package exports a `google` object?. I just had a quick look at their repo and they don't seem to export a `google` member (look [here](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/blob/master/src/index.js)). If they don't export `google` then the following import is the issue.

```js
const {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  google, // this is invalid - there is no 'google' available
} = require("react-google-maps");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add window.google.maps like this and it will work.

```
controlPosition = { window.google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT }
```